# Why the css has not been applied when it is called in a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented a toggle grid/list view. I call those views using this HTML and jQuery code:

It works fine when I call this function from html code, clicking on the `a` link.

The problem is happening when I call the function `ideaView` from another jquery function. In this case, the CSS formatting is not been applied.

For example, when the user make a search, I need to call this function to show the result according to the view that the user choose, but its not working:

I'm not sure if I was clear, I did my best. Tks in advance.

```js
$('a#list-view').click(function() {
  localStorage.setItem("ideaView", "1");
  ideaView(localStorage.getItem("ideaView"));
});

$('a#grid-view').click(function() {
  localStorage.setItem("ideaView", "0");
  ideaView(localStorage.getItem("ideaView"));
});

function ideaView(ideaView) {
  if (ideaView == 1) {
    $('#idea-list-group').removeClass('card-columns');
    $('.idea-cards').css('flex-direction', 'row');
    $('.idea-cards').addClass('mb-2');
  } else {
    $('#idea-list-group').addClass('card-columns');
    $('.idea-cards').css('flex-direction', 'column');
    $('.idea-cards').removeClass('mb-2');
  }
}

function searchIdea(event, form) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = form;
  ....
  ideaView(localStorage.getItem("ideaView"));
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a id="list-view" href="#"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i> </a>
  <a id="grid-view" href="#"><i class="fas fa-th"></i> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are this two functions in the same file? Or it's a different file? Also are you getting any error in console?

Comment: are in the same file. No error in console.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting correct value for 'localStorage.getItem("ideaView")' ?

Comment: Yep. I printed some value in console to be sure. The function has been calling, but the css has not been applied.

Comment: It's ugly and it's not an answer but what happen if you call your **a**  link with $('a#....').click(); from another jquery function ?

Comment: @CrazyProg I've tried it. But it didnt works.

Comment: If you inspect the generated html after calling your function everything is ok ?

Comment: When I inspect it, the css formatting is not applied, despite the function was called.

Comment: Do you happen to have more than one row with list-view and grid-view links? Those both have `id` attributes and those should be unique throughout the document.

Comment: Does the `searchIdea` function do any ajax calls and replaces the `#idea-list-group` node and the `.idea-cards` items ?

Comment: @HerrSerker I check it out and I have just one. I changed it for class to be sure, and it didnt works as well.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli tku so much. That was the problem. I had to change the place where I call the idea view function because of the ajax calls. Tks.